# How to join all elements in array except first one?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a phone number as a string as "+22 123 234 22". I am trying to format as "+22 12323422". Below is a code I am trying. But, the length of the string array won't be constant. What would be the ideal way to do it?

```js
var x = "+12 123 344 22";
var y = x.split(" ");
var z = y[0] + " " + y[1] + y[2] + y[3];
console.log(z);
```

I know I can use a for loop to achieve this as below. But I am looking for something from array methods like "Skip()" in C#.

```js
    var x = "+12 123 344 22";
    var y = x.split(" ");
    var t = y[0]+" ";
    
    for(var a=1; a<y.length; a++){
    t+=y[a];
    }
    
    var z = y[0] + " " + y[1] + y[2] + y[3];
    console.log(t);
```

Comment: @TusharShahi I added the for loop. Sorry, forgot to mention that I am looking for some array method instead  of for loop.

Comment: ok. You can use reduce too for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) might come in handy:

```js
var x = "+12 123 344 22";
var y = x.split(" ");
var z = y[0] + " " + y.slice(1).join('');
console.log(z);
```

A couple of other options:

```js
var x = "+12 123 344 22";

let [h, ...rest] = x.split(" ");
console.log(h + " " + rest.join(''))

let y = x.split(" ");
console.log(y.shift() + " " + y.join(''))

console.log(x.replace(' ', '@').replaceAll(' ', '').replace('@', ' '))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using an array method - `reduce()` and having if condition for first index:

```js
var x = "+12 123 344 22";
var y = x.split(" ");
var z = y.reduce((cum,x,index) =>{
   if(index == 0) return y[0] + " ";
   return cum + y[index];
},"");
console.log(z);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `for loop` to iterate from 1 (excluding first element) to join rest of the split string.

```js
var x = '+12 123 344 22';
var y = x.split(' ');
var z = y.length > 0 ? `${y[0]} ` : '';
for (let i = 1; i < y.length; i ++) {
    z += y[i];
}
console.log(z);
```